# Включение и отключение объекта в коде С# Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class StarHolder : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> ListStars = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject Father;
public bool onoff = true;
public float TimeDela;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GeneratingStar()); //Запуск коротина
}

void Update () {

}
public IEnumerator GeneratingStar(){
    TimeDela = Random.Range (3f, 10f);

    foreach (Transform item in Father.transform) {
        ListStars.Add (item.gameObject);
        if (!item.gameObject.activeSelf) {
            item.gameObject.SetActive (true);            //Для линейного включения
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeDela); 
        }
    }
    //  foreach(GameObject item in ListStars){
    //  ListStars [Random.Range (0, ListStars.Count)].SetActive (true); //Для рандомного включения
    //  yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeDela); 
    //}
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создать `GameObject`, в который будете добавлять звёзды как child, ну и хранить для удобства в `List<ActiveStar>`, скажем `StarHolder`:

```
public class StarHolder: MonoBehaviour {

    List<ActiveStar> m_Stars = new List<ActiveStar>();


    void Update () {
        // прогоняем звёзды
        // если звезда активна, то выключаем, иначе включаем
        Stars.ForEach(star => star.SetActive(!star.activeSelf));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, если я правильно помню, то необходимо обращаться к полю `gameObject` объекта. И тогда получится, что надо писать так:

```
if (onoff == false) {
    testObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
} else {
    testObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Также у объекта есть поле [activeInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html), которая позволяет вам узнать активен ли данный gameObject в игре. На её основе можно написать следующее:

```
myObject.SetActive(!myObject.activeInHierarchy);
```

или [activeSelf](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) - выдает состояние активности данного GameObject'а.

```
myObject.SetActive(!myObject.activeSelf);
```

то есть можно написать метод, который включает/выключает объект

```
void ToggleActive(GameObject obj) {
    obj.SetActive(!obj.activeInHierarchy); // obj.SetActive(!obj.activeSelf);
}
```

и в любой момент, когда вам понадобится - им воспользоваться, например:

```
if (onoff == false) {
    ToggleActive(testObject);
}
```

Ну еще можно (и полезно когда много объектов) заносить объект в список/массив, как пишет в соседнем ответе **@Suvitruf** и уже манипулировать им через него.

---

По коду в обновлении:

> Нужно как раз вот это: "все выключены и надо чтоб одной по одной появились все"

При старте гасите все звезды (если они были включены) через цикл. А прям в самой корутине делаете следующее: в начале из `ListStars` отбираете те, которые еще не включены

```
var filteredData = ListStars.Where(item => item.activeSelf == false).ToList();
```

Затем пишите еще один `Random.Range` от 0 до `filteredData.Count` и сгенерированный индекс активируете

```
filteredData[index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Выглядит примерно так:

```
void Start()
{
    foreach(GameObject item in ListStars){
        item.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    StartCoroutine(GeneratingStar()); //Запуск коротина
}

public IEnumerator GeneratingStar(){
    TimeDela = Random.Range (3f, 10f);

    var filteredData = ListStars.Where(item => item.activeSelf == false).ToList();
    var index = Random.Range(0, filteredData.Count);
    filteredData[index].gameObject.SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeDela);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Вроде разобрался теперь звезды[объекты] появляются, но мне нужно чтобы звезды появлялись по 1 штуке в рандомный интервал времени, а они появляються или все или только 1 штука взависимости от применении строчек:
          item.gameObject.SetActive (true); // появляются все звезды
или
            ListStars[0].gameObject.SetActive(true); // появляется только одна звезда, дальше не работает
            ListStars[1].gameObject.SetActive(true); 
            ListStars[2].gameObject.SetActive(true); 
 попробывал использовать коротин но в самом коротине обектами листа манипулировать не разрешает

Comment: Код выше отредоктировал.

Comment: Кстати что не морочиться с true или false можно дергать у объекта поле activeself и ставить setActive(!activeself) и он будет переключаться в состояние обратное текущему.

Comment: @justyx да, про это забыл. Хотя вместо этого воспользовался activeInHierarchy)) Допишу, пожалуй, в ответ

Comment: @Crozen93 я не понял:  нужно чтоб все звезды гасли - одна появлялась или все выключены и надо чтоб одной по одной  появились все?

Comment: Нужно как раз вот это: "все выключены и надо чтоб одной по одной появились все" думаю через коротин включать по одной звезде, но не пойму как в коротине работать с элементом списка чтобы он включался по 1й звезде.

Comment: @Crozen93 При старте гасите все звезды (если они были включены) через цикл. А прям в самой корутине делаете следующее: в начале из `ListStars` отбираете те, которые еще не включены `var filteredData = ListStars.Where(item => item.activeSelf == false).ToList();`..... Затем пишите еще один `Random.Range` от 0 до `filteredData.Count` и сгенерированный индекс активируете `filteredData[index].gameObject.SetActive(true);`

Comment: Сделал но включение происходит по линейному порядку, если брать закоментированый код то включение происходит по рандомному порядку, но возникает проблема что в  forech может обращатся к одному и тому же элементу списка и за рандома. 
Код отредактировал.

Comment: @Crozen93 я же прям в комментарии выше написал ровно точно то, что надо делать. Там ни строчки про foreach, там упоминается предварительная фильтрация и там упоминается откуда надо доставать объект..............http://pastebin.com/HRuS6vVn